# How do I pass URL parameters from Route to Livewire in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm pretty new to Livewire. I want to pass the URL parameter to the Livewire component and display the result through the view file. I have passed the URL parameter to the Livewire component, but it shows a blank page when I load the page.

Below are my codes

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/brandcategory', [App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::class, 'brandCategory'])->name('brandcategory');
Route::get('/brandcategory/{category}',  App\Http\Livewire\Productcategory::class);
```

**CategoryController**

```
public function brandCategory()
    {
        return view('components.productbrandcategories');
    }
```

**productbrandcategories.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.newapp')

@section('title','Product Category')
@section('content')
<div>
    <!-- Header Area Start Here -->
    @include('inc.header')
    <!-- Header Area End Here -->

    @livewire('productcategory')
   
    <!-- Begin Footer Area -->
    @include('inc.footer')
    <!-- Footer Area End Here -->
</div>
@endsection
```

**Productcategory (Livewire component)**

```
    public $cat;

    public function mount($category)
    {
        $this->cat = str_replace("+"," ",$category);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.productcategory',[
            'products'=> Product::where('category', $this->cat)->paginate(12),
            'categories'=> Categories::all(),
        ]);;
    }
```

**livewire.productcategory**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-40">
      @if (!empty($products))
         @foreach ($products as $item)
            <p>{{ $item->name}}</p>
         @endforeach
      @endif
   </div>                                    
</div>
```

The page when loaded on the browser is just blank, not even the layout component displays.

Please I need help with this.

Comment: You have using a livewire component as a full-page component. I believe you have not configured the right layout for the livewire component to extend that my cause the issue. Check out this link & if still not fixed add file structure to your question.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#custom-layout

Comment: You are not using livewire as it should be, read the docs or learn about it on Laracast :)